# how to put two variables together

Tags: perl

Noob question.  I'm checking if a file exists in perl, but I'm not sure how to put two variables together when I have a sourceFile predetermined, and a path that must be passed in as argument. In other words, how do I concat an argument passed in with another variables so that I could use perl's file test -X function?

```
$sourceFile = 'somefile';

if ( $ARGV[0] && -e ($ARGV[0] + '\' + $sourceFile) )
```

I've also tried:

```
if ( $ARGV[0] && -e ($ARGV[0]\\$sourceFile) )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the simplest, concatenation is simply including the variables the way you want them inside a double quoted string:

```
my $path = shift;        # pulls first argument from @ARGV
my $file = 'somefile';   
if (-e "$path/$file") {  # concatenate the variables
```

You can also use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
my $filename = join "/", $path, $file;
```

Or the [concatenation operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators):

```
my $filename = $path . "/" . $file;
```

Don't forget that while trying to learn Perl, using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

...will help you a great deal with understanding what you are doing and what is happening.

Answer (score 6):

To build a file path, it's safest to use `File::Spec::catfile` to join path components in a platform-independent way.

```
use File::Spec;
if ( $ARGV[0] && -e File::Spec::catfile($ARGV[0], $sourceFile) )
```

Comment: You can import `catfile` by using `File::Spec::Functions` instead. Saves a few keystrokes.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that. I would usually write `use File::Spec qw/catfile/` or the like if I didn't want to use the fully qualified name in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do.

```
$sourceFile = 'somefile';

if ( $ARGV[0] && -e ("$ARGV[0]/$sourceFile") ) {}
```

Strings can be concatenated in perl like this

```
  $string3 ="$string1$string2" ; #1

  $string3 = $string1.$string2 ; #2
```

[This](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/basic.html) is a good place to start learning Perl

Comment: Why do you escape the slash? It doesn't change its meaning. It works, but would be better to suggest a solution using `File::Spec`. More portable.

Comment: Agree! I mistook it for backward slash. Does `File::Spec` take care of paths in Windows ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I use it to avoid headaches when working with paths in different Operating Systems.

Comment: Yes, `File::Spec` goes to great lengths to work on many different platforms.

Comment: @Jean, Windows accepts both `/` and `\ `. File::Spec handles whatever is native, so it accepts both `/` and `\ ` on Windows. F::S canonizes to `\ ` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

use the . to concatenate the variables

```
like $firstname . $lastname
```